# Cannot edit the code while debugging in Azure function using Typescript in VS code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I'm trying to write a http trigger using Typescript language. I have set up every thing while following [Microsoft Azure Function Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode). I used **VS code** for this. The thing is I cannot change the code while debugging. If I do that, It will print below message and stop the operation. Any help I would very appreciate.

[image]

```
[2023-03-06T14:01:50.764Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=e727154c-3aa6-480f-bd8f-80117f8fe5dc, Duration=32847ms)
[2023-03-06T14:02:05.484Z] Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
[2023-03-06T14:02:05.568Z] Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/2f31ec6f-83b3-454f-96d5-84fb64fbb2c2
[2023-03-06T14:02:05.570Z] For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[2023-03-06T14:02:05.792Z] Worker process started and initialized.

 *  The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command func host start" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Note: Parallely, I used `tsm -w` command in vs code in build terminal for compile ts file to js file.

Answer (score 0):

As you are following this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode) to create a JavaScript trigger durable functions, I tried it in my environment, and it worked as per your requirements.

There is a Debug: option in `VScode`. **You can start debugging and stop it on entry,** and you can also utilize the **multiple break points** option to debug code in separate terminals with multiple changes and you can display it in multiple window screens to avoid confusion.

You can go through with the [VScode debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) doc for more relevant information.

***Activity function:***

`index.js`:

```bash
module.exports = async  function (context) {
return `HelloThere ${context.bindings.name}!`;
};
```

I started debugging using `Debug: Start debug and stop on entry`. I was making changes while the function was executing but the terminal is not exited as shown in the below image.

[image]

***Orchestrator URL:***

[localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/DurableFunctionsOrchestratorJS1](http://localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/DurableFunctionsOrchestratorJS1)

[image]

***`StatusQueryGetUri`:***

[image]

Even if I was debugging the activity function while making changes, the terminal would not exit if you used the `start debug and stop on entry` actions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. What I am trying to say is I cannot edit while debugging. If I edit the code after starting the trigger, The program will stop immediatly.

Comment: Once you start the trigger, it will not possible to edit the code while it is running. @MaleeshaRodrigo

Comment: Isn't there any method to do that?